# Use PHP exec shell (codesign) resign IPA on Mac

Tags: php, shell, ipa, codesign

I wrote some code to package channel IPA and resign IPA with shell. When I run this shell in command line it works ok.

Main shell code:

```
#!/bin/bash

name=$1
needchannel=$2
appName="$name.app"
ipa="$name.ipa"
plistName="${name}_${needchannel}.plist"

# echo "${1} ${2} $ipa"
if [ ! -f "./Payload" ];then
    # echo "not exit Payload"
    unzip $ipa
    chmod -R 0777 Payload
else
    echo "exit Payload"
fi  
cd Payload
cd $appName

ipaPath="${name}_${needchannel}.ipa"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "set Channel $needchannel" "Channel.plist"

cd ../..

/usr/bin/codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: xxxx, ooo" --entitlements entitlements.plist "Payload/${appName}"
zip -rq  "./app/${ipaPath}" "Payload"
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

    $webid = $_GET["webid"];
    $appfinder = "./app/";
    $filename = "Channel_".$webid.".ipa";

    if (!file_exists($appfinder.$filename)) 
    {
        $shell = "sh produceApp.sh Channel $webid";

        system($shell, $status);

        if( $status ){
            echo "produceApp error";
            var_dump($status);
             return;
        }
    }
?>
```

I don't know why the shell run success in command line and fail in PHP. 
Can anybody help me.

Everything works except codesign.

ps:i write the shell code in php,run directly,system() return 1;like this:

```
<?php
    $shell = "/usr/bin/codesign -f -s \"iPhone Distribution: xxx, ooo\" --entitlements entitlements.plist \"Payload/Channel.app\"";
    echo "$shell";
    echo "<br>";
    system($shell, $status);
    print_r($status);
?>
```

the chrome show shell is:

```
/usr/bin/codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: xxx, ooo" --entitlements entitlementds.plist "Payload/Channel.app"
```

and function system() return $status is 1..

[web show result of system run codesign...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7srwm.png)

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Is there any error message given? Which kinds of logging did you try?

Comment: And what does failing in php mean? What is the error?

Comment: The shell i changed to  /usr/bin/codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: xxxx, ooo" --entitlements entitlements.plist "Payload/Channel.app",and the system($shell, $status)  return 1....

Comment: thanks,i find the issue,i run shell use current user,but the browser is apache,php run in apache cannot access the keychain...so,the codesign doesn't work correctly...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in path! Log the path when you run php and correct it.

Comment: The shell i changed to  /usr/bin/codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: xxxx, ooo" --entitlements entitlements.plist "Payload/Channel.app",and the system($shell, $status)  return 1....

Comment: thanks,i find the issue,i run shell use current user,but the browser is apache,php run in apache cannot access the keychain...so,the codesign doesn't work correctly...